# How do I make the goal move? (Python, Turtle)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is the code. I don't know why but the goal does not move when I run the code. I am really new to coding so excuse me if it is something silly. Thank you so much for all your help.

```
    if isCollision(player, goal):
        goal.setposition(random.randint(-300, 300), random.randint(-300, 300))
        goal.right(random.randint(0,360))
        goal.forward(1)
```

Should not this make the goal move? No errors were detected in the code. This is a link to the code: https://pastebin.com/mczU1xpu

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine, goal moves to random position on collision. did you try debugging inside the if statement?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. Maybe you have wrong values in variables or `isCollision` gives `False` and this code is never executed. Did you run code in console/terminal to see error messages?

Comment: code works for me. Do you runs in some IDE? Maybe problem is IDE. Did you try to run it directly `python script.py`?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. I think I wasn’t clear enough. The goal moves for me, but it disappears and appears somewhere else. I want it to move around so the turtle chases it if that makes any sense.

Comment: As in, I want the goal to be moving around the same way the turtle or player moves around

Answer (score 1):

Try moving it with

```
setx()
sety()
```

With "sety()" you can control the y-axis and "setx()" you control the x-axis

And instead of using `goal.setposition(random.randint(-300, 300), random.randint(-300, 300))` use `goal.goto(random.randint(-300, 300),  random.randint(-300, 300))`